# Add and edit form in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons 'Add' and 'Edit' in my page. When I try to click the 'Add' button I get one popup form and I fill the details and will be added in to the database. The same thing when I click the 'Edit' button the same form should be displayed with the filled in details. I know how to get the data from the backend. But I am not aware of how should I differentiate the add and edit in one form.

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

I have refered this link and I have added the details for add form.
Can some one help me how do I do the edit?

```
<html>

        <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="create-user" value="Add user">


        <div class="row-fluid top-space-20">
            {% if result | length == 0 %}
            <div>
                <p>There are no user details ,If you want you can add it </p>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <th>user name</th>
                    <th>user duration</th>
                    <th>user Description</th>
                    <th>user requirements</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </thead>
                {% for each_item in result %}
                <tbody>
                    <td>{{each_item.user_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{each_item.user_time}}</td>
                    <td>{{each_item.user_description}}</td>
                    <td>{{each_item.user_requirement}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="edituser" value="Edit">

                    </td>
                </tbody>
                {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="username">user name</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <label for="duration">Duration</label>
                <input type="text" name="duration" id="duration" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <label for="requirements">Requirements</label>
                <input type="requirements" name="requirements" id="requirements"
                    class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <input type="hidden" id='departmentId' ,value="{{department_id}}">
                <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            var dialog, form,
                username = $("#username"),
                duration = $("#duration"),
                description = $("#description"),
                requirements = $("#requirements"),
                allFields = $([]).add(username).add(duration).add(description).add(requirements),
                tips = $(".validateTips");

            function updateTips(t) {
                console.log(t);
                tips
                    .text(t)
                    .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    tips.removeClass("ui-state-highlight", 1500);
                }, 500);
            }

            function checkLength(o, n, min, max) {

                if (o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min) {
                    o.addClass("ui-state-error");
                    updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                        min + " and " + max + ".");

                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            function addUser() {
                var valid = true;
                allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                var username = $("#username");
                var duration = $("#duration");
                var description = $("#description");
                var requirements = $("#requirements");
                var departmentId = document.getElementById("departmentId").value;
                valid = valid && checkLength(username, "username", 3, 16);
                valid = valid && checkLength(duration, "duration", 3, 16);
                valid = valid && checkLength(description, "description", 3, 300);
                valid = valid && checkLength(requirements, "requirments", 5, 300);

                if (valid) {
                    var username = $("#username").val();
                    var duration = $("#duration").val();
                    var description = $("#description").val();
                    var requirements = $("#requirements").val();
                    var departmentId = document.getElementById("departmentId").value;
                    $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + username + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + duration + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + description + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + requirements + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/department/%d/user' % departmentId,
                        data: {
                            'username': username,
                            'duration': duration,
                            'description': description,
                            'requirements': requirements
                        },
                        success: function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                            alert("The user has been added");
                            document.location.href = "/departments";
                        },
                    })

                    dialog.dialog("close");
                }
                return valid;
            }

            dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 400,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Create user": addUser,
                    Cancel: function () {
                        dialog.dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                    form[0].reset();
                    allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                }
            });

            form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                addUser();


            });

            $("#create-user").button().on("click", function () {
                console.log("I am first");
                dialog.dialog("open");
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are Multiple Way to do it, Next time Please Post the code. Let me assume that you were using the 
 Model to view

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form.

**For more details post the code we can help you out**

Here is the updated Answer

```
<tbody>
                    <td>{{each_item.user_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{each_item.user_time}}</td>
                    <td>{{each_item.user_description}}</td>
                    <td>{{each_item.user_requirement}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="edituser btn btn-info" type="button" value="Edit" data-user-id = "{{each_item.user_id}}">

                    </td>
                </tbody>
```

change the id to class

```
       $(".edituser").button().on("click", function () {
           var id = $(this).attr("data-user-id");
           var tempUser;
           for(var user in results){
               if(user.id == id){
                     tempUser = user;
                }
           }
             $("#username").val(tempUser.user_name);
             $("#duration").val(tempUser.user_name);;

            dialog.dialog("open");
        });
```

you can set the value accordingly from using "user id"

and on submit change the value in the  "results" object you using to construct the view

Comment: I tried it.There is no response after I click the edit button. Is there any reason we have to use class instead of id?I have included the edit method after the add method?is it correct?

Comment: If you have multiple element which do same operation you have use something more commong like class selector

Comment: <input class="edituser btn btn-info" type="button" value="Edit" >

is loaded after the page is render

Comment: Hi Thanks,It worked now. I have one more doubt in this. How should I do the different ajax calls for add and edit.As of now the form is opening with values in it. After I edit the details ,the ajax post url should be different.Can you help me in this?

Comment: Guru krishna create one more question and add the thread link here will post the clear answer

Comment: Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386236/different-url-has-to-be-passed-for-same-ajax-c

Comment: I will post Answer please add your code always in the question you were posting otherwise stackoverflow will downgrade the question quality

Answer (score 2):

There are Multiple Way to do it, Next time Please Post the code. Let me assume that you were using the Jquery Model to view

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form.

First Way: One Add button one Edit Button(assuming)

1. set id = "Add" for add id = "edit"
2. On Click on Add but show the empty form and use $( "#dialog-form" .dialog( "open" ); to to open the empty form
3. On click on Edit Set the Value in the form (fetch the value from the database if its required) and then $( "#dialog-form" .dialog( "open" );

Secon Way: One Add button Multiple Edit Button(assuming) for each li
 1. use class selector class ="edit"

```
<button class ="edit" data-form-id = "123">Edit</button>

$( ".edit" ).click(function()
{
  var formId  =  $(this).attr("data-form-id ");

  $( "#dialog-form" .dialog( "open" );
 });
```

**For more details post the code we can help you out**

Comment: I have added my code.Can you please check it. I have edit button for each row. But one add button

Comment: @GuruKrishna check the answer below

Comment: @GuruKrishna check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
 <input type='hidden' name='actiontype'>
```

and set value Edit Or Add then in backend you can read this value and choose action for form